# Unexpected RabbitMQ Queue Feature Loss (spring-amqp)

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

## Background

We've implemented retry mechanism with Spring Boot and RabbitMQ using `spring-amqp`. The RabbitMQ instance is provisioned for high-availability, with one primary and two mirrors. The only policy configured is one effecting all resources (queues, and exchanges), defined as below.

```
ha-mode:    all
ha-promote-on-shutdown: always
ha-sync-mode:   automatic
```

Two Spring Boot services, each running `spring-amqp:2.1.6.RELEASE`. One service publishes a message to a primary working queue, the other consumes from it.

If the consumer doesn't like a message, it attempts to publish that message to a retry queue designated for messages which have been retried the same number of times. The maximum number of retries, and the back-off interval are configurable via application properties. The retry queues are declared to dead-letter back to the primary working queue, to be consumed by the next available consumer. The back-off interval in this case, is implemented via [message-ttl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html), and the queue the retry message is published to is declared with a queue expiration of the `message-ttl` value + 1 minute.

First, the consumer, which has encountered a toxic message, attempts to see if the queue exists using the `AmqpAdmin` interface.

```java
Properties retryQueueProperties = rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName);
if (retryQueueProperties == null) {
    Queue retryQueue = createRetryQueue(currentAttempt);
    declareAndBindRetryQueue(retryQueue);
}
```

If the required retry queue doesn't exist, the consumer will declare it.

```java
retryQueue = QueueBuilder.durable(queueName)
    .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", primaryExchangeName)
    .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", primaryRoutingKey)
    .withArgument("x-message-ttl", ttl)
    .withArgument("x-expires", ttl + 60000)
    .build();
```

And bind it.

```java
rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(retryQueue);
rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(
    BindingBuilder
        .bind(retryQueue)
        .to(retryExchange)
        .with(retryQueue.getName())
);
```

Then immediately sends the message.

```java
rabbitTemplate.send(retryExchangeName, queueName, message);
```

## Problem

Occassionally, we will observe via the RabbitMQ management web interface, retry queues which should have been long expired, but remain with no features. That is, the retry queue is missing all of the critical x-args established at queue declaration that make the implementation work (`x-expires`, `x-message-ttl`, etc...).

**EDIT**: This results in message loss, seemingly because the messages expire but are not dead-lettered, however, the fact that the queue appears to be featureless would contradict this; the `x-message-ttl` feature of the queue is also gone.

We haven't yet been able to recreate this behavior locally.

Comment: When you say "message loss" you mean messages are stuck in this queue because it has no TTL? This makes no sense to me unless some other code is declaring the queue without arguments. DEBUG logging in the admin should help. You could try using the [event plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-events) and listen for queue creation and deletion events. https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

Comment: @GaryRussell I edited the post to elaborate on the message loss. The only place any of these queues are declared always includes the `x` args. When it happens it's almost as if `AmqpAdmin` partially declares, then quits; the logging we expect that would indicate the next retry is just missing. No exceptions or errors in evidence.

Comment: `>`AmqpAdmin` partially declares, then quits;` That's not possible, the args are always passed in `declareQueue()`. `>the messages expire` - how's that possible if all the `x-` arguments are gone - or are you also setting a TTL on the messages themselves? Why are you expiring the queues anyway, if they will only be recreated again when the next error occurs? As I said, listening for queue events might be the best next step.

Comment: @GaryRussell Right, I didn't think it was possible. No per message TTL. Removing the queue expiration is on the table among other "solutions", but we want to understand the cause. I'll report back after experimenting with events.

Comment: We couldn't recreate the issue locally, and the cloud managed RabbitMQ instances we are using on QA, and prod don't permit use of the events plugin. The mystery remains. However, we are opting for a cause unaware attempt at a solution; Remove retry queue expiry, and define DL via admin policy.